# PostgreSQL: Unknown Date Output Format. How Can You Convert Date Output Format?

Tags: php, postgresql, date

I've been storing dates in a PostgreSQL 8.3 database table using a query resembling something like this:

```
INSERT INTO files (date_uploaded) VALUES (now());
```

[According to the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT-TABLE) there are four formats that PostgreSQL 8.3 will output depending on the setup. My select statement is returning an unknown fifth format:

```
01:10:00.57875+00
```

The select statement is a simple select, no funny business:

```
SELECT date_uploaded FROM files WHERE id = 1;
```

I would ultimately like to be able to output the datetime in a Unix timestamp format, however, any format that [PHP's `strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function will work with would be acceptable.

---

Why isn't PostgreSQL outputting one of the four formats that are listed in the documentation?

How can I convert the "unknown" format to a different format, or change the default output format?

---

It seams I created the table column with time, instead of timestamp. This is why the format was messed up.

Comment: This looks like a time output, is that column really a date column ?
Postgresql allows you to format it almost however you want though , see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Comment: As stated in the bottom section of my question, yes, that was the problem I was having. Thanks for the link though, it'll help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's unknown about it, but anyway. If you want epoch just to:

```
select extract(epoch from date_uploaded) from files where id = 1;
```

The question is - why do you want epoch? It's not a format you can show to user, so why bother?

Comment: It seams I created the table column with time, instead of timestamp. Your solution works once the column type was updated. Thank you.